# showing interactive visualizations on personal website

Tags: javascript, widget, data-visualization, squarespace

I have several interactive/animated visualization projects (social network analysis, animated GIS, etc) that I would like to showcase in my website. I would love to build a website like this one https://kateto.net/network-visualization (see 6.2 Interactive JS visualization with visNetwork). Does anyone know where should I start?

Very limited experience with HTML coding and website building so would love to use some website builder tools such as Squarespace or wix, etc. Of course they need to be friendly with a lot of javascript/widgets. Will appreciate your recommendation!

Answer (score 0):

In the same website example you provided, they explained that they are using visNetwork (the r package) & vis.js (used for the visualization).

I highly doubt that website builders such as wix/squarespare/etc would be able to import said libs.

I would recommend just learning web development and make a personal site for your showcase. It'd be a lengthy process however in the long run it'll be worth it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick reply. I have seen some GitHub pages showcasing similar interactive graphs. What are the pros and cons if I pursued that direction?

Comment: @user6606453 GitHub pages is a static site hoster for GitHub Projects, you still need to be able to code to go that route. The main pro with doing it yourself is you aren't locked down to whatever widget/modules/etc that the website builder gives you. The main con is it just takes time to learn how to write code.

Comment: thanks, I am increasingly leaning towards doing it myself. If the learning curve is similar to python or R, I guess I can do it.